# VPN pre-configured router for the UK

Tags: router, vpn

An organization currently has a router, which was configured for [IVPN](https://www.ivpn.net/). During lockdown it has lost its settings and, for "reasons" they don't want to reconfigure it again, but to buy a new one.

When it was bought, British Telecom (the ISP) had a handshake protocol with the router, such that one could only use BT provided routers. I do not know if that is still the case. The current router is hanging off the BT router, with other devices attached to it.

So, it would be nice to use a single router, stead of two, but two are acceptable. Paramount is that it be easily set up by a novice. No downloading configuration files & flashing then. Just browse to 192.168.1.1 and enter the VPN service's use name & password.

A big bonus if it supports IVPN, since they currently subscribe to that, but they are willing to switch VPN services, just so long as they have an off the shelf device with max use name & password to configure.

A priority is delivery time, hoping to have it configured & working in the UK by the weekend.